# Sessions for cordova app?

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, cordova

So I have my sessions configured like this.

```
    app.use(session({
      store: new RedisStore(), 
      key: 'localhost.sid', 
      secret: 'keyboard cat',
      cookie:{ domain: '.localhost.io' }
    }));
```

That works well for my main app, but it looks like with cordova this is a conflict and does not save a cookie for the cordova app. When I remove the `key`, `store`, and `cookie` it seems to work well.

Is there a way to use a Boolean to evaluate if its on my site or on an app?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use cookies in a Cordova app. Use **Token-Based Authentication** instead.

Check this out: https://auth0.com/blog/2014/01/07/angularjs-authentication-with-cookies-vs-token/

Comment: Okay, sounds good. I wonder if its easy to implement token based auth via passportjs. I really dont want to create a whole new login strategy for cordova. Even then what's the best way to evaluate when to use the token based auth vs cookie based for my web based app?